# Disable the integration test phase in pom.xml

Tags: maven

There is a open source project called Apache Any23 , the instructions to checkout and build it are listed at the link below.

https://any23.apache.org/build-src.html

I am unable to to do a mvn clean install by following the instructions because the integration test phase gets invoked by the maven invoker plugin , I have user -Dskipstests etc , but the invoker plugin still gets invoked , I need you to bypass/suppress the integration test phase and the surefire plugin tests and do a successful build.

It this requires a pom.xml change, I need you to send me the updated file and let me know what changes were made.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does the project use the `Failsafe` plugin to run the integration tests? If so, try to skip them this way:

`mvn install -DskipTests`

However, since `skipTests` is also supported by the `Surefire` Plugin, this will have the effect of not running any tests. If, instead, you want to skip only the integration tests being run by the `Failsafe` Plugin, you would use the `skipITs` property instead:

`mvn install -DskipITs`

If you absolutely must, you can also use the `maven.test.skip` property to skip compiling the tests. `maven.test.skip` is honored by `Surefire`, `Failsafe` and the `Compiler` plugins.

`mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

Read more about this [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html).